# Solving the non exact differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, integrating-factor

Solve the following differential equation:

$a(x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y)=xy\frac{dy}{dx}$. --Edited: see edit notes

I am having trouble solving this equation, problems that I run into are outlined below.

First, this is a non-exact differential equation. I will not put the work here, but it can be seen if you put the equation in the form $\frac{dM}{dy}=\frac{dN}{dx}$, and it comes out that $\frac{dM}{dy}\neq\frac{dN}{dx}$. So, integrating factors must be used in order to move forward solving.

But this becomes very difficult. If you choose to multiply your ODE by some function $\mu(x)$ or a $\mu(y)$ or $\mu(x,y)$, attempting to find the integrating factor, nothing cancels and you are left integrating something that cannot be integrated.

I also tried to multiply the ODE by $x^\alpha y^\beta$ (because I originally thought that $N$ and $M$ were sums of products of powers of $x$ and $y$, but this also proved inadequate, as the $a$s in the ODE did not cancel, and you are left with two sides of an equation that you cannot get to equal one another.

Leaving me back where I started- ground zero. Does anyone have any ideas on how to find this integrating factor?

Answer (score 2):

The equation is separable,

$$2a^2y=x(y-a)\frac{dy}{dx},$$

$$2a^2\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{y-a}{y}dy,$$

$$2a^2\log x+C=y-a\log y.$$

Comment: Apologies, I miswrote the ODE, I will nonetheless check and see if it will be able to be separated the way that you did

Answer (score 2):

It's separable
$$a(x\frac{dy}{dx}+2ay)=xy\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$a(xy'+2ay)=xyy'$$
$$2a^2y=xy'(y-a)$$
$$2a^2\int \frac {dx}x=\int \frac {(y-a)}{y}dy$$

---

$$a(x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y)=xy\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$a(xy'+2y)=xyy'$$
$$y'x(a-y)=-2ay$$
This last equation is separable
$$\int \frac {a-y}{y}dy=-2a\int \frac {dx}x$$

Comment: Apologies, I miswrote the ODE, I will nonetheless check and see if it will be able to be separated the way that you did

Comment: @Pascal no problem edit your question

Comment: Great, I think I was thinking too hard and getting ahead of myself with this one. Thank you for your clarity and work.

Comment: I added some lines @Pascal

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Isham's answer (extracting $y'$ from the equation
$$\int \frac {a-y}{y}dy=-2a\int \frac {dx}x$$ that is to say
$$a \log(y)-y=-2a\log(x)+c$$ from which
$$y=-a\, W\left(-\frac{e^{\frac{c}{a}}}{a x^2}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function.

Answer (score 0):

$$a\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\right)=xy\frac{dy}{dx}$$
we can see a common factor of $x\frac{dy}{dx}$
so we can obtain:
$$x\frac{dy}{dx}\left(y-a\right)=2ya$$
so:
$$\int\frac{y-a}{2ya}dy=\int\frac1xdx$$
so:
$$2\ln|x|=\int\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{y}\right)dy$$
$$2\ln|x|=\frac{y}{a}-\ln|y|+C$$
$$x^2y=e^{\frac{y}{a}+C}$$
$$x=\sqrt{y^{-1}e^{\frac{y+C_1}{a}}}$$
and this can then be used solving the Lambert W function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function